# Get values of 2 inputs in the Textarea

Tags: str-replace

My code works well. When I typed everything in the Input 1, output text is displayed in the `textarea` with this difference that for each SPACE will be included a coma `,` means SPACE will be replaced by a coma `,`. This is OK.

Now I want to typed everything in the Input 2, the typed text of Input 2 to be added in `textarea` with this difference the previous text is not removed and new text to be added.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#t1").keyup(function() {
         $('#textarea').val($(this).val().replace(/\ /g,','));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Input 1:
<input type="text" id="t1"/></p>

<p>Input 2:
<input type="text" id="t2"/></p>

<p>Textarea:</p>
<textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="textarea"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previous text from input 1 in one variable and concat it with the text from input 2 and Paste it in the Textarea using **val()** method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your previous text refer to input 1, then try this:

```
 $("#t2").keyup(function() {
      var t1 = $('#t1').val();
      var t2 = $(this).val().replace(/\ /g,',');
      $('#textarea').val(t1 + t2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression from your answers. The following code works well and output is what I want.

Is this code principle and standard?

```
 $("#t1, #t2").keyup(function() {
      var t1 = $('#t1').val().replace(/\ /g,',');
      var t2 = $('#t2').val().replace(/\ /g,',');
      $('#textarea').val(t1 + t2);
 });
```